# How does MySQL CASE work?

Tags: mysql, case

I know that SQL's `CASE` syntax is as follows:

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

However, I don't understand how this works, possibly because I'm thinking about it as about an `if` statement.

If I have a field in table `user_role`, for example, which contains names like "Manager", "Part Time" etc., how do I generate a field `role_order` with a different number depending on the role. In the case of this example, "if user_role = 'Manager' then role_order = 5".

Please note I am looking for a *teach a man how to fish* answer rather than *give a man a fish* answer.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) is more like a switch statement. It has two syntaxes you can use. The first lets you use any compare statements you want:

```
CASE 
    WHEN user_role = 'Manager' then 4
    WHEN user_name = 'Tom' then 27
    WHEN columnA <> columnB then 99
    ELSE -1 --unknown
END
```

The second style is for when you are only examining one value, and is a little more succinct:

```
CASE user_role
    WHEN 'Manager' then 4
    WHEN 'Part Time' then 7
    ELSE -1 --unknown
END
```

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, I am still confused about where it goes inside the rest of the query I tried `SELECT *, your-code AS role_order FROM table` But I keep getting errors. Can you show an example using a whole query? Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out, You are supposed to just end with "END" not "END CASE" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html Thank you!

Comment: For those who did not read the linked docs above, you may not read this comment either, but in case you do: Note that there are two different forms of `CASE`, with very similar syntax, but somewhat different purpose/use... See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12436859/2359271).

Comment: @AirThomas: Actually, what he is describing is the `CASE` *expression*, according to MySQL documentation.  Whereas the OP referenced the `CASE` *statement*.

Comment: @Svip Absolutely correct, I had them reversed. Good catch. (For the sake of keeping the comments clean, +1 this when you've read it and I will delete it as well.)

Answer (score 13):

`CASE` in MySQL is both a [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) and an [expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), where each usage is slightly different.

As a statement, `CASE` works much like a switch statement and is useful in stored procedures, as shown in this example from the documentation (linked above):

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE p()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;

    CASE v
      WHEN 2 THEN SELECT v;
      WHEN 3 THEN SELECT 0;
      ELSE
        BEGIN -- Do other stuff
        END;
    END CASE;
  END;
  |
```

However, as an expression it can be used in clauses:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY
    CASE title
      WHEN "President" THEN 1
      WHEN "Manager" THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END, surname
```

Additionally, both as a statement and as an expression, the first argument can be omitted and each `WHEN` must take a condition.

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN title = "President" THEN 1
      WHEN title = "Manager" THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END, surname
```

I provided this answer because the other answer fails to mention that `CASE` can function both as a statement and as an expression. The major difference between them is that the statement form ends with `END CASE` and the expression form ends with just `END`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a simple example of the use of case that I could play with, this doesn't even need a table. This returns odd or even depending whether seconds is odd or even

```
SELECT CASE MOD(SECOND(NOW()),2) WHEN 0 THEN 'odd' WHEN 1 THEN 'even' END;
```