# Case Expression vs Case Statement

Tags: mysql, case

What is the difference between a [Case Expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and a [Case Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) in MySQL? When can they be used, and what are the benefits of using one over the other?

Case Statement syntax:

```
CASE
  WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
  [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
  [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Case Expression syntax:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [condition] THEN result 
  [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] 
  [ELSE result] 
END
```

These look almost identical, but the initial description for Case Statements is that `The CASE statement for stored programs implements a complex conditional construct.`

So is the significant difference that one is used in stored programs and not usable in normal queries? I tried this out on a query I was playing with and it failed - [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a1cb/8). If this is the case though, why not just use the Case Expression in a stored program?

Are there any other syntactical differences to be aware of, since they seem to be identical?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `CASE` expression evaluates to a value, i.e. it is used to evaluate to one of a set of results, based on some condition.
Example:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'foo'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'bar'
    ELSE 'baz'
END AS name_for_numeric_type
FROM sometable`
```

The `CASE` statement executes one of a set of statements, based on some condition.
Example:

```
CASE
    WHEN action = 'update' THEN
        UPDATE sometable SET column = value WHERE condition;
    WHEN action = 'create' THEN
        INSERT INTO sometable (column) VALUES (value);
END CASE
```

You see how they are similar, but the statement *does not* evaluate to a value and can be used on its own, while the expression needs to be a part of an expression, e.g. a query or an assignment. You cannot use the statement in a query, since a query cannot contain statements, only expressions that need to evaluate to something (the query itself is a statement, in a way), e.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN UPDATE table SET something; END CASE` makes no sense.

Comment: Great description, I understand the difference now. My only confusion is when and how to use the Case Statement, would creating a php query with the statement you wrote work? And i'm assuming the best way to use it would for it to follow a query where you set a variable as the result from another query. E.g. `select @action:=action from table limit 1` and then the query `CASE
    WHEN @action = 'update' THEN
        UPDATE sometable SET column = value WHERE condition;` would that work?

Comment: The `CASE` statement can only be used in [stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html), i.e. procedures and functions defined _in your database_. You cannot perform a `CASE` statement as a query from your PHP script.