# SQL server joining where fields different type

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT qd.new_capid, qd.new_captype, 
cv.*
FROM quotedetailextensionbase qd 
LEFT JOIN new_capvehicleextensionbase cv
ON qd.new_capid = cv.new_capid 
AND qd.new_captype = cv.new_type
```

A pretty straightforward join, except the last line

```
AND qd.new_captype = cv.new_type
```

qd.new_captype is varchar and can either be "car" or "van"
cv.new_type is int and can either be 1 or 2

car = 1
van = 2

Is there some way I could "translate" one to the other to do the join?

Thanks

Comment: Use a CASE statement.

Comment: @TabAlleman ahem, CASE *expression*. (sorry)

Comment: huh.   Thanks.   I never knew there was a difference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436859/case-expression-vs-case-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT qd.new_capid, qd.new_captype, 
cv.*
FROM quotedetailextensionbase qd 
LEFT JOIN new_capvehicleextensionbase cv
ON qd.new_capid = cv.new_capid 
AND (CASE qd.new_captype when 'car' then 1 when 'van' then 2 end) = cv.new_type
```

Answer (score 1):

If there can be only 2 values you can use `CASE` in following:

```
AND case qd.new_captype when 'car' then 1 when 'van' then 2 else 0 end = cv.new_type
```