# MySQL View Logic with Case

Tags: mysql, case, sql-view

I've been tasked with editing one of our MySQL views to include rows it was missing. The problem is the previous view query was using if() statements which we're not capturing all the tables rows for some reason. I am by no means a SQL master and cannot figure this out...

**Original Code Sample:**

```
CREATE VIEW `b2b_data` AS SELECT 
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`uniqueid` AS `callid`,
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`calldate` AS `ENTER`,
if((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal'),`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did`,`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src`) AS `caller_id`,
if((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal'),'outbound','inbound') AS `direction`,
if((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal'),`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src`,substr(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dstchannel`,5,3)) AS `AGENT`,
sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`,
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`,
if((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal'),`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dstchannel`,`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did`) AS `ROUTE`,
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE (((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` = '601') AND (`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'ext-group')) OR ((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` = '601') AND (`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal-xfer')) OR ((`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext` = 'from-internal') AND (`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` in ('143','146','317','318','320','225','214'))))
```

I read online that IF...ELSEIF only works in stored procedures and functions. So I scrapped that idea. I then thought maybe I could use CASE to make the query return what I needed. Needless to say this did not work and clearly was wrong... but it does display the logic I'm trying to use.

**Modded Code Sample:**

```
CREATE VIEW `b2b_data` AS SELECT
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`uniqueid` AS `callid`,
`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`calldate` AS `ENTER`,

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did` AS `caller_id`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` AS `caller_id`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` AS `caller_id`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` AS `caller_id`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` AS `caller_id`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN 'outbound' AS `direction`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN 'inbound' AS `direction`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN 'inbound' AS `direction`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN 'inbound' AS `direction`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN 'inbound' AS `direction`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` AS `AGENT`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` AS `AGENT`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` AS `AGENT`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN substr(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dstchannel`;5;3)) AS `AGENT`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` AS `AGENT`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN sec_to_time(`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`duration`) AS `AGENT_TIME`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`disposition` AS `DISPOSITION`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dstchannel` AS `ROUTE`;
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dstchannel` AS `ROUTE`;
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did` AS `ROUTE`;
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did` AS `ROUTE`;
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did` AS `ROUTE`;
END CASE;

CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src` IN ('143';'146';'317';'318';'320';'225';'214');
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` IN ('143';'146';'317';'318';'320';'225';'214');
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` IN ('143';'146';'317';'318';'320';'225';'214');
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` = '601';
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`recordingfile` AS `RECORDING` FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` WHERE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dst` IN ('143';'146';'317';'318';'320';'225';'214');
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the `AS` clauses in the wrong place. The entire `CASE` expression results in a single value, which you assign the alias to. And you don't use `;` between the `WHEN` clauses or after the case, since that ends the entire query. There's no separator between `WHEN` clauses, and the entire expression is separated from other `SELECT` columns with `,`.

```
CASE `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`dcontext`
    WHEN 'from-internal' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`did`
    WHEN 'from-internal-xfer' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src
    WHEN 'ext-local' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src`
    WHEN 'ext-group' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src`
    WHEN 'from-did-direct' THEN `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`.`src`
END CASE AS `caller_id`,
```

and similar for tall the other `CASE` expressions.

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow and upvote your answer if it works correctly. I have a feeling I wrote it incorrectly all three times... I  was using both commas and semi-colons to seperate the WHEN clauses. Thought I had to because of the MySQL documentation example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Comment: That documentation is for the `CASE` **statement**, which is used in stored procedures; the semicolons are for the end of the statements that it controls. `CASE` **expressions** are described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: See also [Case Expression vs Case Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436859/case-expression-vs-case-statement)

Comment: Thank you Barmar! You were correct about everything. I managed to get it to work, although now I've run into other issues but they are logic issues that I can work through.