# Override SQL Server Default Sort Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

In order to correctly 'match' data to another data source, I'm looking to add something (perhaps a collation?) to this query in order to return results `A-Z 0-9` instead of `0-9 A-Z` as they are now.

```
SELECT TOP 1 order_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY order_id
```

Note that `order_id` is a `nvarchar` field.

For this example, I'm getting order 04394 instead of order ASK284 as I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will force Alpha over Digits

```
SELECT TOP 1 order_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY case when order_id like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end
        ,order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by ordering on a `CASE` expression with each condition:

```
Select      Top 1
            order_id
From        orders
Where       order_id Is Not Null
Order By    Case When Order_Id Like '[A-Z]%' Then 0 Else 1 End,
            Case When Order_Id Like '[0-9]%' Then 0 Else 1 End,
            Order_Id Asc;
```

Comment: "case expression" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436859/case-expression-vs-case-statement