# Db2: Return max of date column with Nulls

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem with a query in Db2. I need to get the MAX value from a date value. If it is Null it should return `9999-12-31` .

Below is my query so far:

```
select
  case
    when max(cancel_dt) is null
    then '9999-12-31'
    else max(cancel_dt)
from table
where <conditions>
```

Comment: What is the error if any?

Comment: 1. You've missed `END` at end of `CASE` statement, so this will not work. 2. You can use `COALESCE` function instead of `CASE`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Do you mean if *all* values are `NULL` (i.e. the result of the `max()` is null) or *any* values are `NULL`?  What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `END` after `MAX(CAncel_DT)` to close your CASE expression.

Personally I'd probably write it as :

```
SELECT
ISNULL(MAX(Cancel_dt), '9999-12-31') as [MAX_DATE]
FROM table
WHERE conditions
```

NB as an aside, thanks to @jarlh's comment I looked up the difference between CASE **statement** and CASE **expression** and found the following very useful:
[Case Expression vs Case Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436859/case-expression-vs-case-statement)

Comment: case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, had to look up the difference but now I know! Amended answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try it the other way round - the CASE within the MAX - like

```
SELECT max( case when Cancel_dt IS NULL then '9999-12-31' 
                 else Cancel_dt
             end)
 FROM table where conditions
```

You could also use coalesce instead oif the case statement:

```
coalesce(Cancel_dt, '9999-12-31')
```

Coalesce will use the scond value in case the first is NULL - so exactly what you want. The coalesce should be inside the max then of cause.

Comment: This query will return '9999-12-31' if any null value exists, but the requrement is to return this value if max value is null. Aggregate functions ignore nulls and can return it only if all the values are nulls (or no rows were found by filter criteria).

Comment: case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: I think this is the correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: @astentx my answer is correct for the question asked. Of cause your comment is right but this was not the question. So I do not understand why my answer was downrated!

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher Because max(isnull(somedate, '9999-12-31')) <> isnull(max(somedate, '9999-12-31')). The question directly states: "I need max value... If **it** is null, **it** should return '9999-12-31'". There's no mention of *any* null and moreover, max(somedate) can return null if all the values are not null if you apply where condition. So I do not see posibilities here.