# field constant using laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

Using laravel/fluent query builder, I'm trying to cause a constant field value to pass through  for a union(ed) selection that is subsequently ordered . I haven't found the recipe to do the following with fluent.  The unions are easy, but how do you get the field constant to work?

Imagine two simple tables (omitted) and a union select:

```
select field1, field2, 'type1' as field3 from table1
UNION
select field1, field2, 'type2' as field3 from table2
ORDER BY field2
```

The best answer I've come up with so far, is to use a DB::query with a query string I manufacture myself. Laravel/fluent does not seem ready to handle this case, given the test cases I've tried.  Using RAW for a select works great, until you try to order the pair of selected table queries.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM 
(
  SELECT fld1A as field1, 'FOO' as field2 from table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT fld2A as field1, 'BAR' as field2 from table2 
)
temp_table order by somefield
```

Comment: You can also use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389713/how-does-mysql-case-work

Answer (score 23):

Using Laravel 4, and using GROUP BY, rather than ORDER BY I believe you can do something like:

```
$t1 = DB::table('table1')
   ->select('field1',DB::raw("'FOO' as field2"))
   ->groupBy('field2');
$t2 = DB::table('table2')
   ->select('field1',DB::raw("'BAR' as field2"))
   ->groupBy('field2');
$result = $t1->union($t2)->get();
```

I found that `$t1` in this case can be an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` or `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, but the union argument (`$t2`) must be of type `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

This means that you may use eager loading with something like:

`$t1 = MyTableModel::with('table3')->select...`

Comment: DB Class: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Answer (score 11):

This way, probably:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw("'FOO' as field2"))
            ->get();
```