# How to get from multiple column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have following table with data :

```
id  send_user_id   to_user_id   status
1      5              56           0
2      5              125          1
3      500             5           1
4      850             5           0
5      5              365          0
6      5              800          1
7      8520           156          1
```

Now i want to get get where send_user_id =5 or to_user_id = 5 and status = 1

I have tried below query

```
select * from mtable
where send_user_id = 5 and status = 1 or to_user_id = 5 and status = 1
```

with above i am getting following data :

```
  id  send_user_id   to_user_id   status
    2      5              125          1
    3      500             5           1
    6      5              800          1
```

but i want **following output** :

```
all_user_id
  125
  500
  800
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does MySQL CASE work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389713/how-does-mysql-case-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE expression:

```
select case when send_user_id = 5 then to_user_id else send_user_id end all_user_id
from mtable
where 5 in (send_user_id, to_user_id) and status = 1
```

And another way that works because because we're dealing with integer columns:

```
select send_user_id + to_user_id - 5 all_user_id
from mtable
where 5 in (send_user_id, to_user_id) and status = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=47b5033555b3466381719988d1bcc753).
Results:

```
> | all_user_id |
> | ----------: |
> |         125 |
> |         500 |
> |         800 |
```

Comment: My where condition is correct. Have you checked my expected output?

Comment: Can you explain this - send_user_id + to_user_id - 5  ?

Comment: In the sum `send_user_id + to_user_id` it's guaranteed that one of the operands is 5, so if we subtract 5 the result will be the other operand which is not 5.