# Multiple IF conditions in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

In my multiple select query I want to include an option which will select from the joined related tables:
teachers, departments.
I want to select if teacher_department_id is one of the met condition to grab it or set to 0

```
SELECT ....

(IF teacher_department_id = 1     THEN
                                  SELECT teacher_summer_salary AS department_one_summer_salary
                                  AND    teacher_winter_salary AS department_one_winter_salary,
                            
 ELSEIF teacher_department_id  = 2 THEN
                                  SELECT teacher_summer_salary AS department_two_summer_salary
                                  AND    teacher_winter_salary AS department_one_winter_salary,
                                  
 ELSEIF teacher_department_id  = 3 THEN
                                  SELECT teacher_summer_salary  AS department_three_summer_salary
                                  AND    teacher_winter_salary  AS department_three_summer_salary,
                            
                            ELSE
                                  0;
                            
                               END IF;),
```

Comment: please provide table structure with few data and expected output.

Comment: Have a look at [How does MySQL CASE work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3389713).